# Unpublish complete Publication

Tags: 2013-sp1, broker, unpublishing

We need to unpublish a complete Publication with thousands of Components and Pages. 
Usually, we can do it unpublishing all using the Publishing Queue but this action blocks the Queue during various days.

Is there an option to delete a complete Publication from the Content Broker and mark it as unpublished in CM?

Comment: How are you exactly unpublishing? It sounds strange that if you simply select the Publication itself and select unpublish, that it would block the queue for several days (if it doesn, please **edit** your question and provide some more details, as that maybe can point to another issue). It sounds like you are using some sort of custom action which selects everything separately, which can take more time to process if your queue contains a lot of items?

Comment: we are unpublishing all the pages and components published individually. But we have thousand of components and pages in this publication. I was looking for a fastest way to do this without put all these components and pages in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at decommissioning the publication target. Here are some links to the documentation. Strictly speaking it's not per publication, but assuming your system is set up in a reasonably standard way, you will achieve the result you want.

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-11A16F5A-717A-4B07-ABFC-0F1C29A1C82F

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-74588DED-4606-468C-8374-3A9DD3DEB510

Comment: Note that decomissioning will not remove any content from the Broker database, so that doesn't completely satisfy the requirements asked here.

Comment: In the same publication target we have another publications that we need to keep. I supose that we can't use this solution. Thanks for the option.

Answer (score 0):

Please also note that making any change manually in the CM and Broker database will void your support status.

**`Clear-TcmPublicationTarget`** - cmdlet to be used to remove the publishing states from CMS.

I would recommend using TOM.API or Core Service to unpublish the items by triggering transaction as **LOW** priority to publishing queue to remove the items from Content Broker database. so that normal content editors publishing will not impact.

Comment: Similar to Dominic's answer, note that the user asks for a removal of items from the Broker database too, not just the CM side.